# Where is the memory leak in com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core:4.11.1?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have two Cassandra clusters one using version 3.11.10 one using 4.0.rc1.
I am now using java driver com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core:4.11.1 to access them.
It uses protocol 4 to access Cassandra 3 and protocol 5 to access Cassandra 4.

When I make select queries to Cassandra 3 all is fine.
When I make the same queries with the same program to Cassandra 4 I get error messages like the following:

```
    2021-05-31 09:50:50,228 ERROR 21891 ResourceLeakDetector               - LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See https://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
Recent access records:
Created at:
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.compositeDirectBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:223)
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.compositeBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:201)
    com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.protocol.SegmentToFrameDecoder.decodeSlice(SegmentToFrameDecoder.java:101)
    com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.protocol.SegmentToFrameDecoder.decode(SegmentToFrameDecoder.java:65)
    com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.protocol.SegmentToFrameDecoder.decode(SegmentToFrameDecoder.java:37)
    io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I don't see what is wrong.

Could anyone help me with this one?

Thanks

Buck

Comment: open jira ticket at datastax-oss.atlassian.net/

Comment: Thanks Alex for the link: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-2947?atlOrigin=eyJpIjoiMWZmNTQxODgxZTc0NDViZWI0NzBhOTk1ZGFjZGY5ZTQiLCJwIjoiaiJ9